# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'UITouch'

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am currently getting an error in this code block for a SpriteKit game. In the if let statement I am getting the following error.

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not
>   'UITouch'

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        StopSideMovement = false
        if let touch = touches.first! as UITouch {
            if touch.locationInView(self.view).x > screenWidth/2 {
                MoveRight = true
            } else if touch.locationInView(self.view).x < screenWidth/2 {
                MoveLeft = true
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how I can fix this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, do not force unwrap and do read up on the `if let` syntax - it wants an optional but you do not give it an optional.

Comment: Just a few notes not related to the question. **1)** Considering your code, if the location of the touch is exactly `screenWidth/2` then never happen. Is it right? **2)** You are using 2 Bool variables `MoveLeft` and `MoveRight`. Wouldn't be easier having something like `var direction: Direction?` with `Direction` declared as `enum Direction { case Left, Right }`?

Comment: Please check the answers we provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
if let touch = touches.first! as UITouch {
```

should be

```
if let touch = touches.first {
```

### Why?

`touches.first` does return a `UITouch?`. But if you add this guy `!` and write

```
touches.first!
```

then you are performing a force unwrap and you are getting (at compile time) a `UITouch`.

So the whole conditional unwrapping is no longer needed.

> Of course you should avoid `force unwrap` an use safer statements (like the `conditional unwrapping`) unless your are **absolutely** sure there will be some value inside the Optional.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the Set's contents are specified as being `UITouch`. So you don't need the downcast. you just need to unwrap it.

```
if let touch =  touches.first {}
```